# Read cron schedule from bash script

Tags: bash, cron

Is it possible to get the schedule for a running job?

If i have this line in my crontab
`* * * * * /home/test/test.sh`

Can i read the `* * * * *` from `test.sh`, and only for that script?

I hoped there was some variable i could read and get the current schedule.

Answer (score 1):

`crontab -l` gives you the current crontab for the user. You could easier cut out the values you need like this: `crontab -l | grep -v "#" | cut -d " " -f 1,2,3,4,5`

Comment: What happens if the current user has multiple cron jobs? What happens if the job is running from for example cron.daily ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get this information as crond does not provide it to the running job.

For user cron jobs (and possibly others) you could define an environment variable in the crontab and have your job read it e.g.

```
cron_scedule='* * * * *'
* * * * * /home/test/test.sh
cron_schedule='1-59 * * * *' 
1-59 * * * * /home/test/test1-59.sh
```

The environment variable `cron_scedule` is passed to the scripts environment for the script to access. This obviously gets a bit messy and unwieldy the more cron jobs/users etc you have.

What is the problem you are actually trying to solve ?